# Persistent local notification iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, localnotification

Is it possible to have a persistent local notification on iOS? I would like a notification when some aspect of an app is enabled, and for that notification to persist until the user disables the function in the app.

The solution I have thus far is to call the following every 60 seconds or so to refresh the notification:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:localNotification];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

However the drawback of this is that the notification is not truly persistent, and also the screen comes on every time the notification fires. Is there a better solution out there?

In android this is simple:

```
builder.setOngoing(true)
```

Comment: In certain circumstances, you may consider a Wallet (Passbook) card which can show data persistently on the lock screen when some conditions (time, location...) are matched. But it's quite restrictive. What exactly are you trying to achieve, i.e. why do you need the notification to persist?

Comment: Guess because some companies just wanted their iOS app to be exactly the same as Android one. There are fundamental differences between the two, just that some people seems not getting it.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible afaik. You also have no control over a sent local notification either.

If you want something to stay in the notification center, use Today widgets.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/NotificationCenter.html